# Correct way of using validatestring?

Tags: matlab

I am trying to search for hello inside a text file in matlab with the following code:

```
 fid = fopen(filename, 'r');
 if (fid == -1) 
    error('cnt open');
 end

 i = 0;
 while (i == 0)

    str = 'hello';
    validStrings = fgets(fid);
     validStr = validatestring(str,validStrings);
    disp(validStr)
    if (line == -1) 
      i = 1;
    else
    fprintf(1, '%s', line);
    end

 end

 fclose(fid);
```

Can i not use validStrings in this case? I get error

```
??? Error using ==> validatestring
Valid strings must be a cell array of strings.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function expects a cell of strings:

```
A = cell(100,1); // use a bigger number if you have a large file
while (i == 0)
    str = 'hello';
    validStrings = fgets(fid);
    j = 1;
    [A{j} remain] = strtok(validStrings, ' '); //or other delimiter than spaces
    while(size(remain,2) ~= 0)
        [A{j} remain] = strtok(str, ' ');
        j = j+1;
    end
    validStr = validatestring(str,A);
    disp(validStr)
    if (line == -1) 
        i = 1;
    else
        fprintf(1, '%s', line);
    end
end
```